Error in GMM Model with pgmm Function in R: "requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments"
I'm working with a panel dataset in R containing around 400,000 observations. I'm trying to estimate a GMM model using the pgmm function from the plm package. The model is fairly complex, but for testing purposes, I've simplified it, and even the simplified version is giving me errors. Here's the code I'm using:
# Create a date column
ene_lfp <- ene_lfp %>%
  mutate(fecha = as.Date(paste(ano_trimestre, mes_central, "01", sep = "-"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

# Define the reference date
fecha_corte <- as.Date("2022-09-01")

# Calculate three months before and after the reference date
seis_meses_antes <- fecha_corte - months(3)
seis_meses_despues <- fecha_corte + months(3)

# Filter for observations within three months before and after the reference date
ene_lfp <- ene_lfp %>%
  filter(fecha >= seis_meses_antes & fecha <= seis_meses_despues)

# Identify individuals with observations both before and after the reference date
individuos_con_ambos_periodos <- ene_lfp %>%
  group_by(idrph) %>%
  summarize(
    tiene_antes = any(fecha < fecha_corte),
    tiene_despues = any(fecha >= fecha_corte)
  ) %>%
  filter(tiene_antes & tiene_despues) %>%
  pull(idrph)

# Filter the dataset to only include those individuals
ene_lfp <- ene_lfp %>%
  filter(idrph %in% individuos_con_ambos_periodos)

# Convert to panel data structure
panel_data <- pdata.frame(ene_lfp, index = c("idrph", "fecha"))

# Define the GMM formula with endogenous variables and instruments
formula_gmm <- lfp ~ edad_65 + pobreza_90 + tiempo_90 + educ2 + sexo + region +
  area + exp + pueblo + chileno + hijos_men5 + hijos_5a13 +
  hijos_13a18 + ecivil + imacec |
  edad_65 + tiempo_90 + educ2 + sexo + region + area +
  exp + pueblo + chileno + hijos_men5 + hijos_5a13 +
  hijos_13a18 + ecivil + imacec

# Apply the GMM model using pgmm
gmm_model_lfp <- pgmm(
  formula = formula_gmm,
  data = panel_data,
  index = c("idrph", "fecha"),
  effect = "individual",
  model = "twosteps",
  transformation = "ld"
)

However, when I run this, I get the following error:
Error in X %*% theta: requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

I’ve verified that:

There are no NA values in the dataset.
The dimensions of the matrices (X and theta) seem to match.
The variables involved are numeric or categorical (which should be handled by pgmm).

What could be causing this error? I'm also wondering if there's an alternative approach to handle GMM estimation with such a large dataset.
Feel free to edit this further based on any other specific details of your analysis!

It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from dput() or reprex::reprex() and any libraries you are using. Check it out: making R reproducible questions.
